# Roman to integer refactored

Tags: ruby, refactoring

I'm writing a method `roman_to_integer(roman_string)`, which translates a roman numeral into its integer: 'IV' to 4, 'XVI' to 16, etc.

```
 ROMAN_TO_INT = {
      "I" => 1,
      "IV" => 4,
      "V" => 5,
      "IX" => 9,
      "X" => 10,
      "XL" => 40,
      "L" => 50,
      "XC" => 90,
      "C" => 100,
      "CD" => 400,
      "D" => 500,
      "CM" => 900,
      "M" => 1000
    }

    def roman_to_integer(roman_string)
      # TODO: translate roman string to integer
      number = 0
      str = roman_string.dup
      until str.size.zero?
        last_two_characters = str.slice(-2, 2)
        if ROMAN_TO_INT.key?(last_two_characters)
          number += ROMAN_TO_INT[last_two_characters]
          str.chop!
        else
          number += ROMAN_TO_INT[str.slice(-1)]
        end
        str.chop!
      end
      number
    end
```

How can I make my method shorter? Rubocop only allows 10 lines. I'm trying, but always ended with at least 13.

Comment: The trick is to shorten your `ROMAN_CONVERTER` hash and handle more cases in your method. Notice that `IV`, `IX`, `XC`, etc. all follow the same pattern: a "smaller" symbol followed by a "larger" symbol means you subtract the smaller from the larger. If you handle this in your method with 3 or fewer lines, you can shrink the hash by 6 and thus meet your goal of 10 lines.

Comment: See also https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/33170/roman-numeral-converter-in-ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An even smaller version, using the same trick as iGian:

```
ROMAN_TO_INT =
{
  i: 1,
  v: 5,
  x: 10,
  l: 50,
  c: 100,
  d: 500,
  m: 1000
}

def roman_to_int(roman)
  numbers = roman.downcase.chars.map { |char| ROMAN_TO_INT[char.to_sym] }.reverse
  numbers.inject([0, 1]) do |result_number, int|
    result, number = result_number
    int >= number ? [result + int, int] : [result - int, number]
  end.first
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really a refactor, but an option to reduce lines:

```
ROMAN_TO_INT =
  {
    i: 1,
    v: 5,
    x: 10,
    l: 50,
    c: 100,
    d: 500,
    m: 1000
  }


def roman_to_int roman
  value_map = roman.split('').map { |e| ROMAN_TO_INT[e.downcase.to_sym] }
  value_map.map.with_index do |e, idx| 
    unless value_map[idx + 1].nil?
    then
      value_map[idx + 1] > e ? -e : e
    else e
    end
  end.sum
end

roman = "MDCCLXXVI"
roman_to_int roman #=> 1776
```

It does not alert in case of invalid roman notation, for example:

```
roman = "VMII" # incorrect notation for 997
roman_to_int roman #=> 997

roman = "CMXCVII" # correct notation for 997
roman_to_int roman #=> 997
```

Answer (score 1):

If the main objective is to reduce the number of lines of code, one could do the following.

**Code**

```
H = {"VI"=>" 4", "XI"=>" 9", "LX"=>" 40", "CX"=>" 90", "DC"=>" 400", "MC"=>" 900",
     "I"=>" 1", "V"=>" 5", "X"=>" 10", "L"=>" 50", "C"=>" 100", "D"=>" 500", "M"=>" 1000"}

def roman_to_integer(roman_string)
   roman_string.reverse.gsub(Regexp.union(H.keys), H).split.sum(&:to_i)
end
```

**Examples**

```
%w| III LXIV CCXXVI CM CMXCVIII MDCCXII |.each {|s| puts "#{s}->#{ roman_to_integer(s)}"}
  # III->3
  # LXIV->64
  # CCXXVI->226
  # CM->900
  # CMXCVIII->998
  # MDCCXII->1712
```

**Explanation**

Regular expressions are parsed left-to-right, so to use one here we need to reverse `roman_string` as a first step. That means we also have to reverse the keys in the hash.

This uses the form of [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-gsub) that employs a hash as its argument. Notice that the keys of `H` are in decreasing of order of size. Here's an example of why I've done that. Suppose `gsub`'s pointer is at `"V"` and the following character is `"I"`. The ordering of the keys will cause `gsub` (which is greedy) to match `"VI"` rather than `"V"`.

For

```
roman_string = "CCXXVI"
```

the steps are as follows.

```
k = H.keys
  #=> ["VI", "XI", "LX", "CX", "DC", "MC", "I", "V", "X", "L", "C", "D", "M"]
r = Regexp.union(H.keys)
  #=> /VI|XI|LX|CX|DC|MC|I|V|X|L|C|D|M/
t = s.gsub(r, H)
  #=> " 1 5 10 10 100 100"
a = t.split
  #=> ["1", "5", "10", "10", "100", "100"]
a.sum(&:to_i)
  # => 226
```

Note that, if we are given

```
ROMAN_TO_INT = { "I" => 1, "IV" => 4, "V" => 5, "IX" => 9, "X" => 10, "XL" => 40,
                 "L" => 50, "XC" => 90, "C" => 100, "CD" => 400, "D" => 500, 
                 "CM" => 900, "M" => 1000 }
```

we can calculate `H` as follows.

```
H = ROMAN_TO_INT.map { |k,v| [k.reverse, " #{v}"] }.sort_by { |k,_| -k.size }.to_h
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ROMAN_TO_INT = {
  "I" => 1,
  "V" => 5,
  "X" => 10,
  "L" => 50,
  "C" => 100,
  "D" => 500,
  "M" => 1000
}

def roman_to_int(roman_number)
  # 1.
  arr_values = roman_number.chars.map {|letter| ROMAN_TO_INT[letter]}
  # 2.
  index_max_number = arr_values.index(arr_values.max)
  # 3.
  arr_values.map.with_index {|number, index| index < index_max_number ? - number : number}.sum
end
```

I post this answer because I think its simple to understand and intuitive. All the methods used and the steps are commonly used.

1. Transform the roman number to the values according to the hash.
2. Find the position in the array of values where the max number is.
3. All the numbers in front of that position will be negative (subtract from the sum). All the numbers after that position
   will stay positive (they will add).