# Roman Numerals Decoder: Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, algorithm, parsing

Alright I've been working on this coding challenge for quite some time and I guess it's officially time for me to raise the flag. Help!

My task is to create a function that takes a Roman numeral as its argument and returns its value as a numeric decimal integer.

So far I've successfully created a hash mapping the numbers to its numeric values. I've also created an empty array `roman_no` to pass the key/value pair through.

What I am struggling with is writing the expression. Below is the full code:

```
def solution(roman)
 # take a value of a roman numeral 
 roman_numeral =
    {
      1000 => "M", 
      900 => "CM",
      500 => "D",
      400 => "CD",
      100 => "C",
       90 => "XC",
       50 => "L", 
       40 => "XL",
       10 => "X", 
        9 => "IX",
        5 => "V", 
        4 => "IV",
        1 => "I" 
      }

roman_no = Array.new
  
roman_numeral.each do | key, value | 
  while 
    "#{roman}" >= "#{key}"
      += roman_no 
    "#{roman}" -= "#{key}"
    end
  
return roman_no

  
 
solution('XXI')
```

How can I write an argument that will take the value from `roman_numeral` and return its number counter part?

for example:

```
solution('XXI') # should return 21
```

Comment: So what is your question?A code review suggestion or your code can not work?

Comment: I just added to question. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the code is supposed to be converting this way around (`solution('XXI') == 21`?) The half-completed code you've got seems to be headed towards converting in the other direction (`solution(21) == 'XXI'`). Also, what you've provided so far is clearly invalid -- it's missing an `end` and contains the mysterious blank line: `+= roman_no`. If you're looking for a complete solution from scratch then this is easily googlable; if you're looking for pointers to get *your* solution working then I'd just like to make sure we're all on the same page about what you're trying to do

Comment: (And that the code you've provided really is the most up-to-date, complete version that you've written?!)

Comment: [Apparent dup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53033844/roman-to-integer-refactored)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Roman to integer refactored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53033844/roman-to-integer-refactored)

Answer (score 3):

```
def solution(roman)
  mapping = {
     "M"=>1000,
     "D"=>500,
     "C"=>100,
     "L"=>50,
     "X"=>10,
     "V"=>5,
     "I"=>1
  }
  # split string into characters
  roman.chars.map do |l|
    mapping[l] # replace character with integer value
  end
  .compact # removes potential nils caused by  invalid chars
  # Splits array into chunks so that we can handle numerals such as IIX
  .chunk_while do |i,j|
    i <= j #
  end
  # each chunk will be an array like [10, 10, 100] or [1, 1, 1, 1]
  .map do |chunk| 
    if chunk.first < chunk.last
      chunk.reverse.inject(:-) # handles numerals such as IIX with subtraction
    else
      chunk.sum # chunk is just a list of numerals such as III
    end
  end
  .sum # sums everything up
end
```

Comment: PS. Remember that you owe me 10% of all your future salaries if you get the job.

Comment: That is a nice "one-liner"  I normally implement this with a loop.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev "valid" is kind of a matter of interpretation as the Roman empire didn't exactly leave an ISO Standard behind. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals#Irregular_subtractive_notation

Comment: haha thanks Max ! definitely going to be going over this a few more times  =D