# Minitests are flaky on pure function without side-effects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I am doing a RomanNumerals kata as a shakedown for my tools, since I'm joining a Rails project next week (yay!), but the tests I wrote fail randomly (boo!).

- Every time I let them run, without any changes to the code I get a different result.
- I'm using `rails test` as a command.
- The versions are fresh off the net. Everything that comes out of `rails new` without any additional gems. (Ruby 2.7.0, Rails 6.0.3)

It seems to be some weird intermix between tests running in parallel and some variables getting overwritten by other tests. Or maybe there is some weird optimization thing involving a cache going on?

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 18166
Run options: --seed 29967

# Running:

.......F

Failure:
RomanNumeralHelperTest#test_18_returns_XVIII [/home/eric/rails/rome/test/helpers/roman_numeral_helper_test.rb:55]:
Expected: "XVIII"
  Actual: "IXVIII"


rails test test/helpers/roman_numeral_helper_test.rb:54

........

Finished in 0.066531s, 240.4883 runs/s, 240.4883 assertions/s.
16 runs, 16 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 18195
Run options: --seed 59433

# Running:

.............F

Failure:
RomanNumeralHelperTest#test_15_returns_XV [/home/eric/rails/rome/test/helpers/roman_numeral_helper_test.rb:51]:
Expected: "XV"
  Actual: "IXV"


rails test test/helpers/roman_numeral_helper_test.rb:50

..

Finished in 0.053298s, 300.2008 runs/s, 300.2008 assertions/s.
16 runs, 16 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 18247
Run options: --seed 14645

# Running:

................

Finished in 0.048711s, 328.4691 runs/s, 328.4691 assertions/s.
16 runs, 16 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

```
class RomanNumeralHelperTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "1 returns I" do
    assert_equal "I", RomanNumeralHelper.convert(1)
  end  

  test "2 returns II" do
    assert_equal "II", RomanNumeralHelper.convert(2)
  end  
  
  test "3 returns III" do
    assert_equal "III", RomanNumeralHelper.convert(3)
  end

  # Intermittent tests omitted. They go from 1 to 20.

  test "20 returns XX" do
    assert_equal "XX", RomanNumeralHelper.convert(20)
  end
end
```

```
module RomanNumeralHelper
  ROMAN_ONE = "I"
  ROMAN_FIVE = "V"
  ROMAN_TEN = "X"
  def self.convert(number)
    result = ""
    current_numeral = ""
    remaining_number = number    

    until remaining_number == 0 do
      if remaining_number > 8
        current_numeral = ROMAN_TEN
        remaining_number -= 10
      elsif remaining_number > 3
        current_numeral += ROMAN_FIVE
        remaining_number -= 5
      else
        result += ROMAN_ONE * remaining_number
        remaining_number = 0
      end      
      if remaining_number < 0
        current_numeral.prepend(ROMAN_ONE)
        remaining_number = 0
      end      

      result += current_numeral
      current_numeral = ""
    end    

    result
  end
end
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, it returns the correct result each time

Comment: I did whats basically a roman numeral one-liner (if you strip the comments) a while back that you might be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/63830535/544825

Comment: @Eyeslandic Interesting. So it's not about the code, it's something weird about my setup? Did you do this on a fresh environment with rails new? Maybe I should put this in a Docker container to make it extra-reproducible...

Comment: @max Pretty cool. Unfortunately, in this case, it's less about the solution and more about getting everything around it working correctly. Thanks though!

Comment: @Eric Yes, it's just a brand new Rails 6.0.3.4 setup with Ruby 2.6.5

Answer (score 2):

My mistake was modifying a constant.

`current_numeral = ROMAN_TEN`

`current_numeral.prepend(ROMAN_ONE)`

I changed the String that ROMAN_TEN referenced. The fix is:

```
ROMAN_TEN = "X".freeze
```

and

```
current_numeral = ROMAN_TEN.dup
```

Also using rubocop - even on a small project like this - would have given me a warning.